# Slowness in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Below is performance profile captured in Chrome while I change React views via `this.props.history.goBack()`. I traced the slow call down the stack, I'm left with ambiguous "Function Call", telling me nothing about where all the time is being taken.

[image]

Also getting this warning:

[image]

Comment: usually, this is a case of components that got rendered even though they shouldn't.
Use why-did-you-update to check if that is true.
https://github.com/maicki/why-did-you-update

Comment: It appears the slowness what waiting for the browser to render 6 high-res images, scaled down as a CSS background.